# Can $(\Bbb Z[x], +)$ be isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q, +)$ as groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Can $(\Bbb Z[x], +)$ be isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q, +)$ as groups?

**My attempt** $:$ We know that $(\Bbb Z[x], +)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q_{\gt 0}, \cdot)$ as groups. Now if there exists a group isomorphism between $(\Bbb Z[x], +)$ and  $(\Bbb Q, +)$ then we have a group isomorphism $\varphi : (\Bbb Q, +) \longrightarrow (\Bbb Q_{\gt 0}, \cdot).$ But then there exists $a \in \Bbb Q$ such that $\varphi (a) = 2 \implies \varphi \left (\frac {a} {2} + \frac {a} {2} \right ) = 2 \implies \varphi \left (\frac {a} {2} \right )^2 = 2 \implies \varphi \left (\frac {a} {2} \right ) = \pm \sqrt {2} \notin \Bbb Q_{\gt 0},\ $ a contradiction. Hence we conclude that there does not exist any group isomorphism (in fact onto group homomorphism) between $(\Bbb Z[x], +)$ and $(\Bbb Q_{\gt 0}, \cdot).$

Am I right? Can anybody please verify my argument above? Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is no need to go through $(\mathbb{Q}_{\gt 0},\cdot)$: for every $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ there exists $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $2b=a$. Is the same true in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? That's what you are doing, but you go through the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, which seems like a long way to go to get where you want to go.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sir yeah you are right. The odd integers can't be written as $2b,$ for some integer $b.$

Comment: Well, tecnically you need to show that the odd integers cannot be written as $2b$ for some *polynomial with integer coefficients* $b$, but yes. Or, just find a single one you can't, and that's enough.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sir if I want to write any integer as $2b$ in $\Bbb Z[X],$ then $b$ has to be a constant polynomial i.e. an integer.which is precisely what I meant to say. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, but uses much more than it's needed.

For every $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, there exists $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a=2b$.

On the other hand, there is no $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $2p(x)=1$.

This is essentially the same argument, but doesn't use the knowledge about $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ being isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}>0$ which is not relevant.

*Any* abelian group that's not [divisible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.